# Why Im get 400 bad request?

Tags: php, codeigniter, curl

I'm using Codeigniter Framework and I want to do something like this:

I want send `$_GET` varibale from server 1 to server 2, like this: `www.server1.com?foo=123`

AND now on server 2, check if the `$_GET==123` return some data.

My code look like this that:

on server 1, example: `www.server1.com?foo=hello`

```
if(isset($_GET['foo'])){
        $post_fields = array(
            'foo' => $_GET['foo']
        );
        $ch = curl_init('http://server2.com/master.php');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,  $post_fields);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        die($result);
    }
```

and the code on server 2 look like this:

```
$variable = $_POST['foo'];
if($variable=="hellow"){
    echo "right!";
}else{
    echo "wrong";
}
```

When I run this code I'm getting 400 bad request - nginx:

Comment: for one, are you allowing get variables? See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/334708/get-parameters-in-the-url-with-codeigniter - also, if you're using CI you may want to consider using `$this->input->post('foo')`

Comment: server 2 not working with CI so i don't need to use $this->input->post('foo'), And in my get variables  allowed...another idea? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

**Server 1:**

```
<?php
 // for debug purposes removed it on production
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
// end debug

if(isset($_GET['foo'])){
        $post_fields = array(
            'foo' => $_GET['foo']);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://server2.com/master.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($post_fields));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);

if ($result == "OK"){
echo "Post OK";
}else{
echo "Post NOT OK";
}

}else{
die("GET NOT Received");
}
?>
```

**Server2:**

```
<?php
 // for debug purposes removed it on production
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
// end debug

if(isset($_POST['foo'])){
$variable = $_POST['foo'];

if($variable=="hello"){
    echo "right!";
}else{
    echo "wrong";
}

}else{
  die("POST NOT Received");
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use something like that may be it helps

```
$url = 'http://server2.com/master.php';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,  $post_fields);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
echo $ret = curl_exec($ch);
```

and also debug the results

Answer (score 0):

You're posting an array so add this line:

```
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, Array("Content-Type: multipart/form-data"));
```

Reference: https://www.php.net/curl_setopt